# Java How do you initialize Ehcache?

Tags: java, ehcache

How do I surround a try catch around my Ehcache in the attempt to make sure it has started correctly?

Comment: Are you doing a programmatic initialization or xml configured initialization ? It would be nice if you can post some more details...

Comment: @Sridhar Yeah I apologize for the lack of detail. I'm new to the ehache so I'm not even sure how to kick off the object properly. I'm initializing it programmatically

Comment: From just your question, you'd probably want to catch `CacheException()` when constructing an `EhCache` implementation. `EhCache cache = null; try { cache = new (WHATEVER CACHE TYPE YOU WANT)() } catch (CacheException ce) { /* something */ }` - I recommend reading the [Getting Started doc](http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/getting-started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write wrapper method which checks the status of cache with CacheManager e.g.,

```
/**
 * 
 * @return true if Caching system is live otherwise false
 */
public boolean isAlive()
{
    return net.sf.ehcache.Status.STATUS_ALIVE == cacheManager.getStatus();
}
```

You can always wrap your caching calls as

```
public Object getVal(Object aKey, Object aDefaultValue)
{
    Element element = null;

    if (Util.isAlive())
    {
        try
        {
            element = cache.get(aKey);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            //Log it
        }
        catch (RuntimeException r)
        {
            //Log it
        }
    }

    return ((element == null) ? aDefaultValue : element.getObjectValue());
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Chandra, I believe this is what I'm looking for :)